# time data '2015-02-10T13:00:00Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, django

I am getting

```
time data '2015-02-10T13:00:00Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

I tried:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-02-10T13:00:00Z', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

and

```
import time
time.strptime('2015-02-10T13:00:00Z', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your format balks because you are not handling the `T` and `Z` characters in your input; you have a space instead of the `T` and no timezone handling.

Comment: Isn't it clear that the template you give doesn't match the date/time you're passing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a quick workaround, you could add `T` and `Z` characters into the datetime formatting:

```
import datetime            #          v  note  v
datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-02-10T13:00:00Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
# datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 10, 13, 0)            #        ^  note  ^
```

But it's better to use something that is able to parse ISO-formatted date & time. For example, [`dateutil.parser`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html):

```
import dateutil.parser
dateutil.parser.parse('2015-02-10T13:00:00Z')
# datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 10, 13, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())
```